# Solr CDCR || CdcrReplicator Log reader for target collection1 is not initialised, it will be ignored

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have setup two solr cloud instances in two different Datacenters
Target solr cloud machine is copy of source machine with basicAuth enabled on them.
I am unable to see any replication on target.

**Solr Version** :6.6.3

I have done config changes as suggested on https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/cross-data-center-replication-cdcr.html

**Source Config Changes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
...
<requestHandler name="/cdcr" class="solr.CdcrRequestHandler">
  <lst name="replica">
    <str name="zkHost">serverIP:2181,serverIP:2182,serverIP:2183</str>
    <str name="source">sitecore_master_index</str>
    <str name="target">sitecore_master_index</str>
  </lst>

  <lst name="replicator">
    <str name="threadPoolSize">8</str>
    <str name="schedule">1000</str>
    <str name="batchSize">128</str>
  </lst>

  <lst name="updateLogSynchronizer">
    <str name="schedule">1000</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
  <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

    <updateLog class="solr.CdcrUpdateLog">
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>


    <autoCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>
  </updateHandler>

  ...
  </config>
```

**Target Config Changes**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
...
<requestHandler name="/cdcr" class="solr.CdcrRequestHandler">
  <lst name="buffer">
    <str name="defaultState">disabled</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="cdcr-proc-chain">
  <processor class="solr.CdcrUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="update.chain">cdcr-proc-chain</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
 <updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">

    <updateLog class="solr.CdcrUpdateLog">
      <str name="dir">${solr.ulog.dir:}</str>
      <int name="numVersionBuckets">${solr.ulog.numVersionBuckets:65536}</int>
    </updateLog>

    <autoCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

    <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>

  </updateHandler>

  ...
  </config>
```

Below are logs from Source target.

```
2018-09-07 08:27:37.220 WARN  (cdcr-replicator-243-thread-5-processing-n:serverip:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.h.CdcrReplicator Log reader for target collection1 is not initialised, it will be ignored.
2018-09-07 08:27:38.858 WARN  (cdcr-replicator-241-thread-1-processing-n:serverip:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.h.CdcrReplicator Log reader for target collection2 is not initialised, it will be ignored.
```

I am unable to see anything on target.
It will be great if someone can help me in it.

Comment: found few more logs on source:
2018-09-07 10:36:17.033 WARN  (zkCallback-4-thread-3-processing-n:serverip:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.h.CdcrReplicatorManager Unable to instantiate the log reader for target collection collection1
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find a healthy node to handle the request.
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.sendRequest(CloudSolrClient.java:1377)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient.requestWithRetryOnStaleState(CloudSolrClient.java:1134)
 at ...

Answer (score 0):

It got resolved long time back.

Try following steps.

1. Restart Solr Server
2. Stop CDCR for all indexes
3. Restart CDCR for all indexes